# "In" or "on"? Which preposition to use?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition would be the right one to use in this context?

"I have published a number of papers in/on theoretical syntax."

Is there a meaning difference?

Comment: Don't you want to use "about?"

Comment: Can I use "about" if the papers are about a topic within the field of theoretical syntax?

Comment: Yes, why not. You can also use "on." When you use "in" it usually means _where_ you have published them. Google "published papers on" and "published papers in" (with quotes) and you'll see.

Comment: If you use **in**, that means that it was written not in English but in the language of *theoretical syntax*. (What that would look like, I have no idea.) *I wrote a book **in** French*, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

A paper is **on** a particular subject, but **in** a particular field.